# Angular 2/4 Displaying count of unread/ unseen messages

Tags: angular

I was trying to implement a message displaying app(just like gmail do) in Angular 2/4.
I need to display the count of unread messages(say `inbox.component.ts`) on the sidebar(say `sidebar.component.ts`).

In inbox component I have a variable(say `unSeenMsg`) that holds the value of unread messages(initialized on `ngOnInit()` ), on hitting one of unread messages I reduce the count by one `this.unSeenMsg = this.unSeenMsg-1`.

Is there any method to inform the sidebar the value of `unSeenMsg` .

Talking about the flow, I have a layout component(sidebar is a children of this one)
inbox is another component that initialized in a later time

Hope some one can help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service with a variable of type subject

```
export class notifyServic {
    private unseenCount = 0;
    unSeenMsgChange: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
   UpdateUnseen(count: number) {
        this.unseenCount = count;
        this.unSeenMsgChange.next(this.unseenCount);
    }
}
```

Once you get the data initially you can set it in the component as,

```
this.conversation.getMessages().subscribe(resultmessages => {
    this.notifyServic.UpdateUnseen(this.resultmessages.length);
}, error => this.errorMessage = error);
```

and then use in another component as,

```
notifyServic.unseenCount;
```

Comment: Hi brother, it partially works in my case. I need to update the count on the sidebar, it loads first and the updation of variable unseenCount happens only when user access that component( hitting inbox in my case ). I need to inform the updated value to sidebar here what happens is that sidebar always display unSeenCount as 0 (More precisely in my case sidebar never loads again after being initialized)

Comment: You can use the same convept and use proper lifecycle hook

Comment: Other thing you can do is making the call twice in both components

Answer (score 1):

Read https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction .

Now here is a little example. Parent component:

```
this.updateChild = this.unSeenMsg;
```

In the html of parent:

```
<sidebar [childCounter]=updateChild ></sidebar>
```

In the child component:

```
@Input() childCounter: any;
```

And show the childCounter in the sidebar html.

Comment: Thanks but in my case these components are not having a parent-child relationship at all